# siunitx removes a decimal zero

Tags: siunitx

I am trying to typeset the value 2.4 +/- 0.009 using the `siunitx` package and the `\num` command. However, once I switch `siunitx` to show the uncertainty with a `\pm` character, it removes one decimal zero.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \num[separate-uncertainty=true]{2.4 \pm 0.009} \\
    \num[separate-uncertainty=false]{2.4 \pm 0.009}
\end{document}
```

Result:

> 2.40 ± 0.09 (missing one decimal)
>
> 2.40(9) (also incorrect, see comment)

Am I making a mistake, or is there something wrong in the `siunitx` package? Or did I miss a necessary option?

*Edit*: I apparently misunderstood the meaning of the [parenthesis notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty), where the number in parenthesis is the ± value for the digit(s) left of it. However, this just means both typesetted values are wrong, and not only the first as I had assumed initially.

*Edit 2*: I just contacted the package's author. Apparently he is aware of the problem, and as Bernard commented below, consideres the input invalid (since it does not have enough digits for the given uncertainty). However, he will have a look at it.

Comment: Nothing is wrong - you have just misunderstood the notation of uncertainty. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty

Comment: @hpekristiansen: Admittedly, I misunderstood the meaning of the parenthesis notation (will edit this in a second). However, that just means that both results are simply wrong? If I explicitly state to have `2.4 \pm 0.009`, I do NOT want anything to change this to `2.4 \pm 0.09`, since this isn't a question of notation anymore.

Comment: Ok - I see now. Bernard gives the solution - you need the correct number of digits on the number part of the input.

Comment: There is a bug _but_ the input is defective (there simply are not enough significant digits).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write `\num{2.40\pm 0.009}` or `\num{2.400 (9)}`.

Comment: This actually solves the problem. Would anyone consider this a bug to report, or is there reason behind it that I don't see?

Comment: Not sure,but I think conventionally, an uncertainty cannot have more decimal digits than the estimated value.

Comment: I accepted this answer now. I understand the idea about the number of digits, however still think the current behaviour of the package simply is wrong since it modifies the numbered input.